# AlpacaJS: observer for dynamically added objects in array's

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, observers, alpacajs

I hope someone can give me a hint. Ic created a form which has different array fields. One of them has two drop downs where the entries in the second one are depending on the choice of the first one. THis should be easy to solve with an observer and just load the values in the second one after the choice in the first one has changed. So far no problem.

But now the issue, if I test this for a static fieldset that's easy, but I could not figure out how I have to address the observer for dynamically added fields.

Also, I'm not sure if there is an option to address the fields relative and not absolute. Would be much easier as I have to set the values always in the actual object.

Here is a small fiddle setup https://jsfiddle.net/ygwuxrbk/

```
{
        "schema": {
            "title": "Erfassung",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "title": "Account",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "services": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "title": "Services",
                        "required": true,
                        "uniqueItems": true,
                        "items": {
                            "description": "Angebotenen Services des Anbieters",
                            "type": "object",
                            "id": "arr_item",
                            "properties": {
                                "category": {
                                    "type": "select",
                                    "title": "Service Kategorie",
                                    "required": true,
                                    "$ref": "#/definitions/categories"
                                },
                                "service": {
                                    "title": "Service",
                                    "type": "select",
                                    "enum": service["Beauty & Wellness"]
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                 }
            },
            "definitions": {
                "categories": {
                    "enum":
                    categories
                },
            }
        },
        "options": {
            "fields": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Category",
                    "onFieldChange": function (e) {
                            console.log(this.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "form": {
            "attributes": {
                "action": "http://testcompany.com/echo.php",
                "method": "post"
            },
            "buttons": {
                "save": {
                    "title": "Save",
                    "click": function(e) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(this.getValue()));
                        //this.submit(); // submit it via regular HTTP post
                        this.ajaxSubmit(); // submit via ajax
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I found my issue. I was just using the wrong path structure.

Answer (score 0):

The path to use in the above example is

```
                 "options": {
            "items": {
                "fields": {
                    "services": {
                        "items": {
                            "fields": {
                                "category": {
                                    "events": {
                                        "change": function() {
                                            console.log(this.value);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```